# Flutter Navigator.replace and Navigator.replaceRouteBelow

Tags: android, flutter

How to use `Navigator.replace() and Navigator.replaceRouteBelow()`. I find these two method in Navigator.dart, and try it. 
From A navigate to B, then to C. And perform this code in C:

```
Navigator.replace(context,
            oldRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PushPageB()),
            newRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PushPageD()));
```

And app crashed, this is the log:

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1673 pos 12:

'oldRoute._navigator == this': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially

more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

2      NavigatorState.replace (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1673:12)

3      Navigator.replace (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1041:34)

4      ReplacePage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_navigation/replace_page_demo.dart:45:31)

5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)

6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)

7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)

8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)

9      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)

10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)

11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)

12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)

13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)

14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)

15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)

16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)

17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)

18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:153:13)

19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:107:5)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)

Handler: onTap

Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#7d65d(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: possible, 

won arena, finalPosition:
  Offset(233.6, 383.8), sent tap down)
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I just want to know how to use these two functions.

Comment: as you can see `oldRoute._navigator == this` is not true: most likely `oldRoute._navigator == null`, now see in the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart) when `_navigator` field is assigned and you will know what `oldRoute` to pass to `replace` method

Answer (score -1):

```
'oldRoute._navigator == this': is not true.
```

Show that old route need equals this

Additional, I never use Navigator.replace, instead I use like this

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage());
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

Hope it helps